# British attitudes towards their country's responsibility for Palestinian-Israeli conflict

Tags: united-kingdom, israel, public-opinion, palestine

Are there any opinion polls regarding Britain's legacy/responsibility for the colonial policies in Mandatory Palestine?

The question is prompted by the [mistreatment of two October 7 survivors by Manchester Airport security](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2024/mar/26/uk-investigating-claims-hamas-attack-survivors-faced-antisemitic-abuse-at-airport), and also by the notorious [anti-Israeli rhetoric by Jeremy Corbyn and his followers over the years](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2016/sep/13/the-lefts-jewish-problem-corbyn-israel-and-antisemitism-dave-rich-review). While such attitudes towards Israel and Israelis are by no means unique to Britain, the UK—of all the western nations—is probably the least entitled to a holier-than-thou position towards Israelis and Palestinians, as it oversaw the development of the conflict over the period of the [British Mandate for Palestine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandate_for_Palestine).

Indeed, both sides in the conflict routinely blame the British. Palestinians simply claim that Zionism was a part of the British colonial enterprise. The Palestinian position, e.g., is expressed at length in ["The Iron Cage"](https://books.google.fr/books/about/The_Iron_Cage.html?id=x5znEAAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y)  by [Rashid Khalidi, an American-Palestinian professor at Columbia University](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashid_Khalidi):

> [...] the British government of the day
> always intended to subvert even this highly conditional projected
> extension of independence to the Palestinians. This is clear from the
> minutes of a British cabinet meeting of February 23, 1939, detailing
> the British approach that resulted in the White Paper of 1939, in
> which this promise was embodied. There it appears that **the British
> colonial secretary, Malcolm MacDonald, and his cabinet colleagues
> meant to prevent Palestinian representative government and self-
> determination, even while appearing to grant the “independence”
> of Palestine.**
>
> Similarly, the United States, the first country to recognize the
> independence of the Jewish state in May 1948, has yet to support in
> deed (as opposed to word) the independence of Arab Palestine.
> [...]
> On the contrary, in practice the United States is, and
> for over sixty years has been, one of the most determined opponents
> of Palestinian self-determination and independence. It has aligned
> itself closely with the Israeli position: thus, only when the position
> of Israel on this matter changed in 1992–95, under the government
> of Yizhaq Rabin, did U.S. policy change.

Traditional pro-Israeli historians largely adopt the opposite view, although equally unfavorable to the British (see, e.g., Walter Laqueur's [A History of Zionism](https://books.google.fr/books/about/A_History_of_Zionism.html?id=F2a6uQAACAAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y)) - claiming that Britain reneged on the promises in the [Balfour declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balfour_Declaration) immediately after taking control of Palestine: Notably, the already mentioned [White Paper of 1939](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Paper_of_1939) restricted the Jewish immigration to Palestine at the moment when German Jews were still able to flee Germany, but were denied asylum by most European states. It was in response to the White paper that the Palestinian Jews began actively organizing clandestine immigration and [military insurgency against the British](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_insurgency_in_Mandatory_Palestine), which eventually led to the establishment of Israel in 1948.

*Clarification: I am not asking about general British attitudes towards the current events in Palestine, but about the attitudes towards the UK's historical role, its historical guilt/responsibility, the humility that the British past role might provoke.*

Comment: https://qr.ae/ps2CiE

Comment: I'm not aware of any; I would expect the majority of responses to be "Don't know / no opinion." The history is not something that is widely taught. See e.g. https://www.theguardian.com/education/2017/mar/28/uk-exam-boards-drop-israel-palestine-syllabus-school-teachers.

Comment: Very few countries make a point of teaching embarrassing chapters of their history in schools. I can only think of Germany, actually, as an example of a country whose official curriculum very much does not try to hide at least one particularly egregious period of its history. All nations have dark chapters, but they tend to avoid mentioning them in polite company.

Comment: @terdon: yeah, how many in the US even remember/know that the US turned back ships with Jews when the war was breaking out. https://www.history.com/news/wwii-jewish-refugee-ship-st-louis-1939

Comment: @thegodsfromengineering for the saint Louis ship is there any evidence that that was because of racism though? I read most of the article and it seems to me that their refugee status was disputed (which was stupid, but seemingly not uncommon for the time). Also, afaik the US was letting in a decent amount of jews, especially scientists.

Comment: @terdon "Very few countries make a point of teaching embarrassing chapters of their history in schools" - there's also a lot of history and not a lot of lesson time.

Comment: The British empire of that time was pretty harsh to what it considered its lesser subjects

Comment: Not my down or close votes but my guess is they come from the second paragraph. What is the general attitute? Here is two examples of anti-Israel sentiment. Doesn't look like a neutral way of presenting the issue but seems rather like a push question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced you can get more than narrative answers [from a few people] to your very specific question, but the broader issue of attitudes towards the [former] colonies of the British empire [does](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/mar/11/uk-more-nostalgic-for-empire-than-other-ex-colonial-powers) get polled a bit.

[image]

Possibly as part of an attempt to win 'hearts and minds' in the Arab/Muslim world, one does occasionally hear speaches [like](https://www.opendemocracy.net/en/opensecurity/forgotten-lessons-palestine-and-british-empire/) (paraphrased):

> In a speech to the Oxford Centre for Islamic Studies on 21 May 2009, David Miliband, the British foreign secretary, argued that the future of the west’s relations with Muslim-dominated countries lay in the building of broad coalitions based upon consent among citizens—not just ruling elites. Prior to making his case, he acknowledged the elephant in the room of Anglo-Muslim relations: Britain’s colonial record in the middle east and south Asia, and its legacies. As part of this rare confession of culpability, he noted ‘the failure – it has to be said not just ours - to establish two states in Palestine’.

From the full speech transcript [here](https://reliefweb.int/report/occupied-palestinian-territory/our-shared-future-building-coalitions-and-winning-consent), it was attempting to be somewhat more balanced:

> Ruined Crusader castles remain as poignant monuments to the religious violence of the Middle Ages. Lines drawn on maps by Colonial powers were succeeded, amongst other things, by the failure - it has to be said not just ours - to establish two states in Palestine. More recently, the invasion of Iraq, and its aftermath, aroused a sense of bitterness, distrust and resentment. When people hear about Britain, too often they think of these things.
>
> These events are associated with a history of relations between Europe and the Islamic world that have been characterised by conquest, conflict and colonialism. But there is a different tale to be told. It does not erase the conflict, but it does establish a different narrative.
>
> It is a history not of conflict or confrontation, not even of coexistence or tolerance, but of interchange and mutual contribution. It is the history of 17th century Iran - as told so impressively in the current British Museum exhibition. Of 13th century Andalucia, Norman Sicily or the European enlightenment, of St John of Damascus, Christian advisor to Umayyad Ruler, of dialogue between Byzantine Emperor and Arab Caliph and the discovery of Greek thought by early Islamic scholars.

Speaking of advisers to Muslim rulers etc., this doesn't seem to get acknowledged as much by politicians these days, but the British policy in the early days of Israel had somewhat contradictory goals, e.g. the Foreign Office wanted/preferred for much of the Arab inhabited lands to end up under a British allied/aligned ruler like the king of Jordan, and the UK e.g. voted tactically at the UN [in '48] on ceasefire demands in order to achieve [that](https://www.declassifieduk.org/when-britain-aided-israels-ethnic-cleansing-of-palestine/). However that was counterbalanced by arms embargoes that the British imposed (on all sides) giving Arab armies enough arms “to enter the war, but not enough to win”, in the words of one Egyptian. Aside from history geeks and those circles with a keen interest in the Middle East, you probably don't hear such details discussed in the UK, in general. As one commenter under the Q noted "there's also a lot of history and not a lot of lesson time".

Comment: Interesting. I hope for some polling data. As for *there's also a lot of history and not a lot of lesson time* - the question received four anonymous downvotes and two closure votes, so I suppose that it is more than just ignorance.

Comment: @RogerV. there’s only likely to be polling if someone pays for it, and there aren’t currently any likely parties to do so (on any of the three sides) who’d then release the data.

Comment: hong kong definitely was better off for having been colonised by UK? many filipinx & indians find better lives in nearby hong kong.